# Easier way of testing and adding Javascript to a page in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to extend some Javascript in one of my pages and for quick "will this work" code it's a huge pain. Basically it consists of editing code in my IDE and save, switch to Firefox, reload page, set breakpoint in Firebug, examine and repeat

Are there any Firefox extensions that will aid me in this respect?

The only thing I can find is using `javascript: ...` in the address bar, but that's a huge pain, can only hold a single line, and there is no way of making the test code persist across a page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the js console that comes with firebug.  You can write all manner of code in there and even declare functions and variables that can be referenced. if you need more than one line, firebug can do that too.

EDIT: except page reload.... if you need to do page reload it needs to be saved somewhere. I would use a Greasemonkey script

Comment: Greasemonkey is actually what I'm trying out right now and it seems to be fairly good except I don't see any way of debugging it. I wasn't aware Firebug had a console

Comment: Ok I figured out how to make the Firebug console work. It also has a `persist` option and a multiline input. I'm going to say it's close enough

Comment: no I don't think you can debug Greasemonkey scripts in firebug, so you would have to output debug info manually (e.g. alert(info) or console.log(info)).

Comment: sweet... I didn't know about the persist part XD

Answer (score 3):

Try [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). You can experiment with html, css and code within your browser and debug that with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for example. You can use a diversity of js-frameworks (or none), simulate XHR, and add your own (js/css)resources. It's not ideal, but much better than the practice you described.

You can also try using [KomodoEdit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), which offers 'view in browser' functionality, even for URLS and with a preset browser.

Comment: See I would normally do this, but I need to write the code in the context of my own page(including it's 20+ javascript script includes)

Comment: Also, that looks just like jsbin, but more suited to experimentation than a "pastebin" type of thing

Comment: The script includes shouldn't be a problem, you can include them in jsfiddle too.

Comment: Added a link to KomodoEdit. Very good and fast free editor for JS.

Comment: no I can't, not easily. Half are ASP.Net script includes, another half are local copies of jQuery and plugins, another part are custom scripts we've made. This is significantly more trouble than what I'm currently doing, at least when working with local pages

Comment: And you're not using Visual Studio then?

Comment: @KooiInc let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1709/discussion-between-earlz-and-kooiinc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Web Console (new in Firefox 4 and higher) - press Ctrl-Shift-K to open it for a particular page. The command line is at the bottom, press Shift-Enter on the command line to enter more than one line.